# Why isn't Python importing this correctly?

Tags: python

So, I have two files, HelloWorld.py and EnterExit.py. Here is the code for HelloWorld:

```
import EnterExit
print('Hello world!')
print('What is your name?')
myName = input()
print('It is good to meet you, ' + myName + '!')
end()
```

And this is EnterExit:

```
def end():
    print('Press enter to continue')
    input()
```

When I run HelloWorld, it works until end() is called. Then it says end() isn't defined. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either write:

```
EnterExit.end()
```

Or:

```
from EnterExit import end       # or import *
end()
```

Comment: And if you want to import all functions from your custom module:

from EnterExit import *

.. Although i wouldn't recommend it.

Nice answer john.

Answer (score 3):

It is importing things correctly, you just need to refer to `EnterExit.end()`.

Alternatively, import `end` directly into your own globals:

```
form EnterExit import end
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `EnterExit.end()`, or alternatively

```
from EnterExit import end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call it like `EnterExit.end()` - there's nothing called `end` in `HelloWorld` itself.

If you want to call it as just `end()`, you need to use

```
from EnterExit import end
```